# SMS to HTTP post

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, sms-gateway

I am trying to receive an sms on a specific url using csoft two way messaging, the method i want to use is SMS to http (http://www.csoft.co.uk/sms/api/sms_to_http.htm).
I am using c#, asp can anyone help me in what do i have to do in my aspx page in order to receive the sms?

Answer (score 0):

Did you not download the sample c# applications from their own website as a starting point?

[Visual C# .NET Send SMS Application Source Code](http://www.csoft.co.uk/sms/example_code/index.htm#vc#net1)

Comment: Yes i did, infact i used it to send an sms. The problem is how can to receive the sms. I already made the set up for two way messaging. the question i have is how to receive an sms.

Comment: I'm assuming you've looked at the incoming spec: http://www.csoft.co.uk/sms/api/sms_to_http.htm. You should edit your question to clarify what it is you've tried and show some code.

Comment: the problem is i dont have an idea of what can i do exactly. Username and PIN should be sent, and the data inbound is SentTo, Message, ReplyTo. I need the code that i have to make in the aspx page.

Comment: OK, sounds like you're pretty early on in terms of what you need to know. I would start with an ASP.NET primer. http://www.asp.net/web-forms. You're going to need to be able to build a page to take POST data and work with it to read the messages sent.

Comment: yes i was thinking about making:
<form method="post">
pass Username and PIN
</form>
???

Comment: No that would be if you want to prepare form data and post it to another url. You need to be retrieving the form data that has been POSTed to your page. You need to be reading up on Request.Form(<fieldname>)